# Can't figure out how to award a bounty on this question

Tags: support, bounty

I was blown away by the thoroughness of the answer to my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547389/why-are-there-two-assignment-operators-and-in-r) and have wanted to award a bounty to the accepted answer.

Yet, I can't seem to find a button or link anywhere on the question's page to award that answer a bounty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question has been reopened, you might want to start the bounty now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question's closed, so you can't award a bounty on it.

Reading the question, I would admit that it's fairly opinionated, but...I could be wrong.  You could cast a reopen vote and hope that four others see it the same way that you do.

*Then* you could place (and award) a bounty on the question.